# Flask and html get values from a text file

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I need to replicate the functioning of Flaskr example (the minimal blog application),
but instead of populating the fields of the output with the database contents I am getting those values from a text file in the disk. 
I am not sure how to read values from a text file and print them, here is the code used to retrieve values from the DB:

```
 {% extends "layout.html" %}
 {% block body %}
  {% if session.logged_in %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('main') }}" method=get,post class=main>
     <dl>
      <dt>Available: 
      <dd><input type=text size=15 name=available>
      <dt>Used frequency:
      <dd><input type=text size=15 name=used>
      <dd><input type=submit value=Update>
     </dl>
    </form>
  {% endif %}
     <table border="1" style="width:300px">
       <ul class=localDB>
       <tr>
       </ul>    
         <th></th>
         <th>MyValues</th> 
         <th>maxValue</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>Available</th>
         <td>{% for entry in localDB %} {{ entry.available }} {% endfor %}</td>
         <td>N/A</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>Used</th>
         <td>{% for entry in localDB %} {{ entry.used }} {% endfor %}</td>    
         <td>N/A</td>
       </tr>
       </ul> 
     </table>
 {% endblock %}
```

Do I have to use other tools like JavaScript or I can use Flask and get the result I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how to read from a file and split the first and second lines.

```
file = open('newfile.txt', 'r')
available = file.read().split('\r\n')[0]
used = file.read().split('\r\n')[1]
print file.read()
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Andrew I need to read a text file containing 'available' values in 1st line and 'used' values and print those values instead of <td> {{ available }} </td> and <td> {{ used }} </td> in a HTML file

Comment: well you could split on the line return in the file.  I'll update my answer with that code.

Comment: Actually I got the answer: i just need to add variables sent with return render_template('main.html', myAvailable=available , myUsed=used) and get them in HTML using {{myAvailable}} and {{myUsed}}